# Searching array for correct letter grade and displaying it with loops

Tags: vb.net

My program first has the user enter in the points possible, then after pressing btnCreate, it displays the grading scale in the lstBox.  After that it passes focus to txtEarned, the user enters the points earned, and then presses the btnDisplay, which in turn displays the appropriate letter grade based on the grading scale created. **btnDisplay is not displaying the correct letter grade at all.  It displays "F", however if i keep pressing btnDisplay it changes to D,C,B, then A.**

```
Option Explicit On
Option Strict On
Option Infer Off
```

Public Class frmMain

```
Dim dblPossible As Double
Dim dblEarned As Double
'Dim dblPercentage As Double
Dim dblMinimumPoints() As Double = {0.0, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9}
Dim strGrade() As String = {"F", "D", "C", "B", "A"}
Dim gradeIndex As Integer = 0


Private Sub txtPossible_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPossible.TextChanged
    ' disable the Display Grade button until the user creates a new grading scale, then
    ' clear the grade

    btnDisplay.Enabled = False
    lblGrade.Text = String.Empty
End Sub

Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
    ' displays a student's grade
    For Each minimum As Double In dblMinimumPoints
        If dblEarned >= minimum Then
            lblGrade.Text = strGrade(gradeIndex)
            gradeIndex += 1
        End If
    Next

    txtEarned.ReadOnly = False


End Sub

Private Sub btnCreate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
    ' fill arrays with values

    Double.TryParse(txtPossible.Text, dblPossible)
    Double.TryParse(txtEarned.Text, dblEarned)

    For counter As Integer = 0 To 4 Step 1
        dblMinimumPoints(counter) *= dblPossible
        lstBox.Items.Add(dblMinimumPoints(counter).ToString)
    Next

    ' enable the Display Grade button 
    btnDisplay.Enabled = True
    txtEarned.ReadOnly = False

    txtEarned.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub txtPossible_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtPossible.Enter
    txtPossible.SelectAll()
End Sub


Private Sub CancelKeys(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtPossible.KeyPress
    ' accepts only numbers and the Backspace key

    If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub txtEarned_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    lblGrade.Text = String.Empty
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: You should reset gradeIndex. Try putting a breakpoint in the function and see what exactly the program is doing line by line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it!  I just moved Double.TryParse(txtEarned.Text, dblEarned) from btnCreate_Click to btnDisplay_Click.  I was a scope problem.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see dblEarned being set anywhere which means it will always be an F. The reason the grade changes each time you click the button is because gradeIndex will be incremented each time and its not reset.

To solve, set dblEarned before the loop and reset the gradeIndex to 0.
See below for a quick revision

```
Private Sub btnDisplay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDisplay.Click
gradeIndex = 0
dblEarned = SETVALUE
For Each minimum As Double In dblMinimumPoints
    If dblEarned >= minimum Then
        lblGrade.Text = strGrade(gradeIndex)
        gradeIndex += 1
    End If
Next

txtEarned.ReadOnly = False 
End Sub
```